# How to derive this equality when deducing Kelvin's Theorem?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

I can't understand how to obtain this equality from [the deduction of Kelvin's Theorem](https://wikimili.com/en/Kelvin%27s_circulation_theorem#Poincar%C3%A9%E2%80%93Bjerknes_circulation_theorem):
$$\oint_C\boldsymbol{u}\cdot(\mathrm{d}\boldsymbol{s}\cdot\nabla)\boldsymbol{u}=\frac{1}{2}\oint_C\nabla(|\boldsymbol{u}|^2)\cdot\mathrm{d}\boldsymbol{s}$$
where $\boldsymbol{u}$ is the velocity vector and $\mathrm{d}\boldsymbol{s}$ is an element along the closed contour.
I have known about this vector identity:
$$\boldsymbol{u}\cdot\nabla\boldsymbol{u}=\nabla(|\boldsymbol{u}|^2/2)-\boldsymbol{u}\times(\nabla\times\boldsymbol{u})$$
Combine these two equalities and I will obtain this,
$$\oint_C\boldsymbol{u}\times(\nabla\times\boldsymbol{u})\cdot\mathrm{d}\boldsymbol{s}=0$$
Why on earth could this term be zero???

Comment: You can't learn anything about $\boldsymbol{u}\cdot(\mathrm{d}\boldsymbol{s}\cdot\nabla)\boldsymbol{u}$ from $\boldsymbol{u}\cdot\nabla\boldsymbol{u}$. Instead, work in index notation with [Einstein notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein_notation) viz. $u_i(\mathrm{d}s_j\partial_j)u_i=u_iu_{i,\,j}\mathrm{d}s_j=\frac12(u_iu_i)_j\mathrm{d}s_j$.

Comment: @J.G. thx a lot! I've understood!